# Opening PDF file on the browser instead to start download automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.open

I have been facing an issue on my code for opening PDF files. The code is:

```
window.open(url_pdf_file, "_blank");
```

The issue is:

On the same user's browser, a PDF file has been opened automatically by the browser and the user can read the PDF file on the browser, but for others PDF files the download operation has been started automatically and the browser has not been opened.

Is there a way for **always opening the browser for the user?**

Comment: Send `Content-Disposition: inline`

Comment: @RyanWilson I don't think this is related to Composite.